# Blinked image when cursor enter in the image

Tags: javascript, css, shopify, rendering, effect

I am making a simple zoom effect when the cursor moves over the image, the only problem I have is that when the cursor enters the image it starts to blink.

Estoy haciendo un efecto de zoom sencillo cuando se desplace el cursor sobre la imagen, el único inconveniente que tengo es que cuando el cursor va entrando a la imagen este empieza a parpadear.

This is in a shopify store, I don't have access to the img tag, only can work with this classes.

I try to change the transform origin and add a backface but the problem persist.

Javascript:

```
function habilitarZoom() {
    const images = document.getElementsByClassName('rimage__image');
  
    for (let i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {
      const image = imagenes[i];
      const container = image.parentNode;
  
      contenedor.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
        const imageRect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
  
        const offsetX = (event.clientX - containerRect.left) / containerRect.width;
        const offsetY = (event.clientY - containerRect.top) / containerRect.height;
  
        const translateX = (imageRect.width - contenedorRect.width) * offsetX;
        const translateY = (imageRect.height - contenedorRect.height) * offsetY;
  
        image.style.transformOrigin = `${offsetX * 50}% ${offsetY * 50}%`;
        image.style.transform = `scale(2.5) translate(${-translateX}px, ${-translateY}px)`;
      });
  
      contenedor.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        image.style.transformOrigin = 'center center';
        image.style.transform = 'scale(1) translate(0, 0)';
      });
    }
  }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    habilitarZoom();
});
```

CSS:

```
.rimage__image {
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}

.rimage__image:hover {
  transform: scale(2.5);
  }

.rimage-wrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please add a working code snippet that reproduces your issue. Otherwise it would be hard for us to help you. And please PLEASE do not write code in other languages other than english. It would be a pain for other developers to debug/change/add to your code in the future.